# SDXC card non recognised

Tags: drivers

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on two desktop en one labtop computers, each with CD reader which is recognized and working. I bought a new SDCX 64Gb card (Philips UHS-I microSDXC Card). The card does not open on each of the computers mentioned. Doe I need to conclude that this card is defective, or is there a known problem with this type of card on Ubuntu 22.04?
I have no other possibility to test the card unfortunately....
Thanks for advice!
Freddy, ON7VQ

Comment: Look at the f3 package (fight fake flash) to test the card.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the card. That should give you a hint.